# Why is $ undefined when jQuery is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this in the head of a page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#ListBoxSegment").change(function () {
            GetAccountOpportunityTypes($(this).val());
        });
        $("#ListBoxType").change(function () {
            GetNumberOfContacts();
        });
    });
```

Running the page gives this error:

```
0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined
```

Why is $ undefined when jQuery is loaded in the line above?

IT WAS FIXED BY LOADING FROM THE URL:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

But still a little strange that it wouldn't load from local.

Comment: try to use jQuery instead of $ and see if you still have the same error.. if so, jQuery is definitely not loaded!

Comment: 0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined

Comment: Jesper, your jQuery is not loaded that's for sure.. try @Brad's suggestion to load jQuery from CDN and see if it helps.. Also, make sure you write your code within $(document).ready(function () { // your code.. });

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is likely that jQuery isn't being loaded.  Check the network tab of your browser tools to see if there is a 404 or something on the jQuery JavaScript file.  Otherwise, this wouldn't happen.

Also, consider loading jQuery from a CDN to take advantage of caching that occurs from site to site:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't know why my browser suddenly doesn't want to load the local jQuery. The path is fine, as I tried to browse to /scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js and there were no problems, however, loading from your URL fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Make sure you mark @Brad's suggestion as an answer. And please tell us if you use asp.net master pages for your project..

Comment: I'm not, it's just a single aspx page.

Comment: @Jesper Note that your page use a *relative* path for jQuery. Unless the page is in the root directory, where the `scripts` directory is, it will not resolve to `/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js`. You might change it to a *relative-to-root* path by placing a `/` at the start of the path -- `src="/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"`.

Comment: Also, you can try <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveURL("~/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js") %>"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I was using IE, and i had the same issue.For me it was fixed when i cleared the cache and cookies in the browser options.